# Why is this result in the for statement?

Tags: c

I just learning for statement

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int i = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        printf("%d", i);    // 0~9
    }

    printf("\n%d", i);      // 10

    return 0;
}
```

in this code

in spite of i < 10, how can i reach 10?

Comment: `i` *did* reach 10, and your output should prove that. Reaching 10 is what broke the loop.

Comment: Do you mean to print the 10 in the loop? Like `i <= 10`?

Answer (score 1):

This `for` loop is equivalent to,

```
int i = 0;
while(i < 10){
    printf('%d', i);
    i++;
}
```

So,

| i at loop start | condition check | i at loop end |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | `true` (loop run) | 1 (i = 0 + 1) |
| 1 | `true` (loop run) | 2 (i = 1 + 1) |
| 2 | `true` (loop run) | 3 (i = 2 + 1) |
| 3 | `true` (loop run) | 4 (i = 3 + 1) |
| 4 | `true` (loop run) | 5 (i = 4 + 1) |
| 5 | `true` (loop run) | 6 (i = 5 + 1) |
| 6 | `true` (loop run) | 7 (i = 6 + 1) |
| 7 | `true` (loop run) | 8 (i = 7 + 1) |
| 8 | `true` (loop run) | 9 (i = 8 + 1) |
| 9 | `true` (loop run) | 10 (i = 9 + 1) |
| 10 | `false` (break) | - |

So, last `i` value of the table is 10 (`i` is now 10). That means, when loop breaks, `i` is 10. That's why you can print `10` after the loop.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in the code, you have set this `i < 10` condition in the `for-loop`. Due to this condition, the loop is ending when the value of `i` is getting equal to `10`. Although the value of `i` is still incrementing to `10` but it is getting printed outside the loop due to this `i < 10` condition. So, in order to print it inside the loop just use `i <= 10`. The loop won't terminate unless the value of `i` reaches more than `10`.

Answer (score -1):

Increment i where you have the print statement after the for loop.
Where the // 10 comment is.

To reach 10 in the for loop, replace it with:
for (i = 0; i <= 10; i++)
Where i <= 10 means (in English) keep looping while i is smaller than or equal to 10.

Comment: This doesn't actually address the OP's question, read it carefully.